# Web service is not worked in iis7

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7

I have a web service in my ASP.NET web service project I want to host it in IIS 7 I got an error

```
error Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.
```

Please provide me step by step solution.

Comment: You should first debug your Web Service in order to identify what causes this error. I suspect a .xml file from the error (check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443441/load-aspx-file-into-xmldocument), but without knowing the actual code that causes this, a solution is hard to be found.

Comment: post the request going to the web service, you can find it in firebug.

Comment: do you have a like statement with the % wildcard? you might have forgotten the quotes in a sql statement.